# Find the distance of the matrix $B$ from $M^\perp$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, solution-verification

> In a unitary space $M_3(\Bbb R)$ with the standard dot-product $\langle A,B\rangle=\operatorname{trace}\left(AB^T\right), A,B\in M_3(\Bbb R)$ there is a subspace
> $$M=\{X\in M_3(\Bbb R): XA=X\}$$
> where $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&0\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix}$.
>
> Find the distance of the matrix $B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&1\\1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$ from $M^\perp$.

---

**My attempt:**

$$XA=X\iff X(A-I)=0\iff X\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\1&0&0\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}=0$$

So, $X$ must be of the form $X=\begin{bmatrix}a&b&-b\\c&d&-d\\e&f&-f\end{bmatrix},\quad a,b,c,d,e,f\in\Bbb R$

$$M=\operatorname{span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&1&-1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&-1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&1&-1\end{bmatrix}\right\},\quad\dim M=6$$

The transposes of the base matrices in $M$ always have two zero-columns and the basis is orthogonal, so I chose the basis for $M^\perp$ by looking at the non-zero columns of the transposes:
$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

Let $B=\Lambda+\Omega,\quad\Lambda\in M,\Omega\in M^\perp$. This decomposition is unique and we can see that:
$\Lambda=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\1&0&0\\1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\Omega=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

So the distance $d\left(B,M^\perp\right)=\|\Lambda\|=\sqrt{\operatorname{trace}\left(\Lambda\Lambda^T\right)}=\sqrt{\operatorname{trace}\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&3\end{bmatrix}\right)}=2$

May I ask if this is correct?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except that $\sqrt{\operatorname{trace}\pmatrix{1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&3}}$ should be equal to $\sqrt{5}$ rather than $2$, your answer is correct.

In this question, there is actually no need to calculate any basis. Since $XA=X$ is equivalent to $X\pmatrix{0\\ 1\\ 1}=0$, we have $M=\{[u,v,-v]:u,v\in\mathbb R^3\}$ and $M^\perp=\{[0,w,w]:w\in\mathbb R^3\}$. Hence every matrix $B=[x,y,z]$ can be written as a sum of two components $P=\left[x,\frac{y-z}{2},\frac{z-y}{2}\right]\in M$ and $Q=\left[0,\frac{y+z}{2},\frac{y+z}{2}\right]\in M^\perp$, and the distance from $B$ to $M^\perp$ is just $\|P\|$.